# visual studio 2008 solution release version runtime fatal error

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, release, runtime-error

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution which consists of some projects and uses dll's with theirs' headers. In the debug version it (the solution) works really well. And in release version it compiles successfully, but on executing some functions which are defined in a dll file it fails.

As I said, the solution works fine in debug mode, and options set properly. Tried turning off
optimization, turned on debugging information, it didn't help. What can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What is the error? Try putting __declspec(dllexport) void fn(..)

Comment: Most likely bug that causes different behaviour between debug and release is an uninitialised variable.

Comment: http://www.flounder.com/debug_release.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this happen many times before.  In *almost every single case* the problem was found to be an out-of-bounds error when writing to an array or other data structure.  In other cases, an uninitialized variable was being used.

You have a bug in your code.  That is certain.  When you build under Debug settings, the compiler does a whole lot of stuff for you that masks certain types of problems.  The compiler will write code that zero-initializes some stuff, masking uninitialized variable problems.

First thing I wold try is cranking up the warning levels to their highest settings.  You should be doing this all the time anyways.  This will very often reveal the problem.  Just be sure to *fix* the problems the compiler tells you about.  Don't mask them with `#pragma`s or chintzy casts.  Next step through your code to isolate the problem.  This can be difficult and time consuming, but there's a silver lining.  Whatever the problem is, the likelyhood of you repeating that mistake is inversely proportional to how long and how hard it is to identify and fix the bug. :)

Comment: Yes, I now realised that I have a variable named deviceList of type vector<device> where 'device' is  a structure. It appears to be causing most of the problems. I declared it within a class, but as I know, STL class 'vector' calls its constructor to initialize deviceList. Can't see any error here. Or can the compiler be ignoring the declaration because of optimization?

Comment: @Nabijon:  Extraordinarily unlikely.  Just put out of your mind any thought of the *compiler* being at fault here.