# Visual Studio 2008 Release Hell

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, release, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [visual studio 2008 solution release version runtime fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800777/visual-studio-2008-solution-release-version-runtime-fatal-error)

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution which works fine in debug mode, but fails in release mode. I found out that I have a variable devicleList of type std::vector where 'device' is a structure. I tried deviceList.clear() and stepped into clear() function, but it appeared that the function doesn't know anything about deviceList.begin() and deviceList.end(). Watch window shows only '???' for any field of these pointers. And at last I got fatal error. As I know, std::vector default constructor initializes objects of this type by default. So, where could the problem be? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't pay to much attention to what your debugger says. It can get confused by template code. And obviously you haven't found a bug in `std::vector`. Most likely explanation for a program which works in debug mode but not in release mode is that you have an uninitialised variable somewhere in your code.

Comment: Does the watch window show "???" in release mode debugging? If so, this is expected...

Comment: You should post the code to your struct which is in the vector.

Comment: In release mode you don't have debug symbols. That why you get '???'